# What's wrong with the Square and Rectangle inheritance?

Tags: ruby, oop, liskov-substitution-principle

I've read some of article about the practice that making Square an inheritance class of Rectangle class is a bad practice, saying it violate  the LSP (Liskov substitution principle). I still don't get it, I made a example code in Ruby:

```
class Rectangle
    attr_accessor :width, :height
    def initialize(width, height)
        @width = width
        @height = height
    end
end

class Square < Rectangle
    def initialize(length)
        super(length, length)
    end
    def width=(number)
        super(number)
        @height = number
    end

    def height=(number)
        super(number)
        @width = number
    end
end


s = Square.new(100)

s.width = 50

puts s.height
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Lumpy Space Princess? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJTrD3R5cj0

Comment: Wow, that's interesting, but I can't quite get it

Comment: yozloy, apologies, I was just making a point that you may want to explain what you meant by LSP so that those who aren't aware of it don't have to search.

Comment: Please don't link to external code-hosting services as your questions *only* content. Your question needs to be self-contained and answerable without depending on any external links.

Comment: who cares as long as it does what you want and passes the spec?

Comment: @AdamWaite: the SO community cares - there's a good chance that this website will outlive others that might host the question content.

Comment: @maerics, I don't think Adam was commenting on the external link issue, I suspect he was commenting on the actual question, since "passes the spec" seems to have nothing to do with external links and everything to do with "if code works, use it".

Comment: @paxdiablo I think you are correct Adam meant the question itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not always keen on Liskov since it seems to limit what you can do with inheritance based on behaviour rather than "essence". In my view, inheritance was always meant to be an "is a" relationship, not an "acts exactly like" one.

Having said that, [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) goes into detail as to *why* this is considered bad by some, using your exact example:

> A typical example that violates LSP is a Square class that derives from a Rectangle class, assuming getter and setter methods exist for both width and height.
>
> The Square class always assumes that the width is equal with the height. If a Square object is used in a context where a Rectangle is expected, unexpected behavior may occur because the dimensions of a Square cannot (or rather should not) be modified independently.
>
> This problem cannot be easily fixed: if we can modify the setter methods in the Square class so that they preserve the Square invariant (i.e., keep the dimensions equal), then these methods will weaken (violate) the postconditions for the Rectangle setters, which state that dimensions can be modified independently.

So, looking at your code alongside the equivalent `Rectangle` code:

```
s = Square.new(100)            r = Rectangle.new(100,100)
s.width = 50                   r.width = 50
puts s.height                  puts r.height
```

the output would be 50 on the left and 100 on the right.

But, **this** is the important bit from the article, in my view:

> Violations of LSP, like this one, **may or may not** be a problem in practice, depending on the postconditions or invariants that are actually expected by the code that uses classes violating LSP.

In other words, provided the code *using* the classes understands the behaviour, there is no issue.

Bottom line, a square is a proper subset of a rectangle, for a loose-enough definition of rectangle :-)

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. One thing I don't get from your `Rectangle` code is the line `r = Rectangle.new(100)`, do you mean `r = Rectangle.new(100, 100)`?

Comment: @yozloy, yes, apologies, that was a cut'n'paste error though I could have claimed it was a single argument Rectangle constructor which made a square :-) Fixed now.

Comment: @paxdiable got it! talking about the output of the `s.height`, and `r.height`, I think `50`, `100` are the right outputs, am I correct about this point?

Comment: @paxdiable why making squares and rectangles a subclass of Quadrilateral is not violating the LSP?

Comment: @yozloy, actually you're right, that too would be a violation. I've removed that paragraph but I'm coming more around to the idea that LSP is of limited real-world use.

Comment: @mko The wiki article also lists several "solutions" for the "problem" (in quotes because I, too, think the LSP is a bit silly in many or most cases), one of which, "Allow for a weaker contract on Ellipse", is the solution you implemented in your original question.

Comment: i think in this case the problem is what we expect from a rectangle. if we expect a rectangle to have its dimensions independent from one another, then of course a square is not a rectangle at all and it's on us. i set the width of the rectangle, then the height and i expect the width to stay the same. is this something a rectangle promises us? we expect something from a rectangle that is not true for all rectangles.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with it from an Liskov substitution principle (LSP) perspective is that your `Rectangle`s and `Square`s are mutable.  That means that you have to explicitly reimplement the setters in the subclass, and lose the benefits of inheritance.  If you make `Rectangle`s immutable, i.e., if you want a different `Rectangle` you create a new one rather than altering the measurements of an existing one, then there's no problem with violating LSP.

```
class Rectangle
  attr_reader :width, :height

  def initialize(width, height)
    @width = width
    @height = height
  end

  def area
    @width * @height
  end
end

class Square < Rectangle
  def initialize(length)
    super(length, length)
  end
end
```

Using `attr_reader` gives getters but not setters, hence the immutability.  With this implementation both `Rectangles` and `Squares` provide visibility to `height` and `width`, for a square those will always be the same, and the concept of area is consistent.

Comment: Ugh! I can see where you're coming from and it's a good explanation. But it appears this makes object re-use rather more difficult. In order to resize an object, you have to create a brand new one with modified attributes then destroy the old. That doesn't make your answer any less valid, just that it reduces the usefulness of LSP in my eyes.

Comment: @pjs why mutable lose the benefit of inheritance? I think Just reimplement the setter methods, `Square` class can reuse the methods defined in `Rectangle` class, is that a kind of benefit?

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm not advocating LSP, just trying to explain (my understanding of) it.  However, I do tend to endorse immutable objects.  A rectangle with different dimensions is a different rectangle!  This makes things much safer in many cases.  For instance, consider putting a bunch of rectangles in a binary search tree ordered by their areas.  Now if you change the dimension of one of them, the tree will start to mysteriously fail for future accesses -- one of its elements suddenly violates the tree's fundamental ordering property.  Bugs like that can be really hard to track down.

Comment: @yozloy: The more you have to rewrite methods to make them work in a subclass, the more you're saying the subclass isn't really an extension of its parent class, it's a separate thing.  The more code you have to put in the subclass, the less you're leveraging inheritance.  Notice that in the immutable rectangle, I didn't have to add or override anything but the initializer.  Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to defend LSP as superior or inferior to alternative views, just pointing out some of the design considerations.

Comment: @pjs You mean rewrite methods in subclass is bad?

Comment: @yozloy Not quite - I mean rewriting methods in a subclass is bad if there's a better architecture.  If you're rewriting lots of methods then an interface might have been a better design choice than inheritance.  I use interfaces when an abstraction with a common name, such as area, has entirely different implementations for different classes, such as trapezoid vs triangle vs circle.  An interface tells me that all geometric shapes have the concept of an area, but the implementation of the concept is class-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the abstract base class or interface (whether something is an interface or abstract class is an implementation detail rather irrelevant to the LSP) `ReadableRectangle`; it has read-only properties `Width` and `Height`.  It would be possible to derive from that a type `ReadableSquare`, which has the same properties but contractually guarantees that `Width` and `Height` will always be equal.

From `ReadableRectangle`, one could define concrete type `ImmutableRectangle` (which takes a height and width in its constructor, and guarantees that the `Height` and `Width` properties will always return the same values), and `MutableRectangle`.  One could also define concrete type `MutableRectangle`, which allows the height and width to be set at any time.

On the "square" side of things, an `ImmutableSquare` should be substitutable for both an `ImmutableRectangle` and a `ReadableSquare`.  A `MutableSquare`, however, is only substitutable for a `ReadableSquare` [which is in turn substitutable for a `ReadableRectangle`.]  Further, while the behavior of an `ImmutableSquare` is substitutable for an `ImmutableRectangle`, the value gained by inheriting a concrete `ImmutableRectangle` type would be limited.  If `ImmutableRectangle` were an abstract type or interface, the `ImmutableSquare` class would only need to use one field rather than two to hold its dimensions (for a class with two fields, saving one is no big deal, but it's not hard to imagine classes with a lot more fields, where the savings could be significant).  If, however, `ImmutableRectangle` is a concrete type, then any derived type would have to have all the fields of its base.

Some types of square are substitutable for the corresponding types of rectangles, but a mutable square is not substitutable for a mutable rectangle.