# Does overloading violate Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: c++, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I am newbie in OOP. Recently I have read about Liskov Substitution Principle.

In the code given below, **Square** class inherits **Give_Area**. Suppose **Square** class has something to do related to a square(like validity check). **Give_Area** gives area of square(4 vertex are on the perimeter of a circle) and area of a circle. So, If I am given a **Radius**, I've to print area of the circle and square(consists of vertexes placed on the perimeter of that circle). To get the area of a circle, I have used a parameter. But there is no parameter when getting area of square. Thus I have done overloading here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

class Give_Area
{
    public:
    double Radius;

    double Area(double pi)
    {
        return pi*Radius*Radius;
    }

    double Area()
    {
        double temp = sqrt(2.0)*Radius;
        return temp*temp;
    }
};

class Square : public Give_Area
{
    public:
    bool Validity()
    {
        //checking validity
    }
};

int main()
{
    Give_Area* area = new Square();
    area->Radius = 3.0;
    cout<< "Area of Circle: " << area->Area(3.14159) <<endl;
    cout<< "Area of Square: " << area->Area() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is..

```
Is this overloading violating Liskov Substitution Principle?
```

If this code is violating, then would anybody please give me an example of an overloading which will not violate Liskov Substitution Principle?

I googled my query but have found nothing. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The properties of the Shape should be encapsulated in the shape itself as member variables and not passed as arguments to the area getting methods.

Comment: I may actually be in the minority here but I consider Liskov to be a bad thing, in that it limits unnecessarily what you can do, knowing how the stuff is meant to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804817/whats-wrong-with-the-square-and-rectangle-inheritance/16804908#16804908. Boottom line, provided you _understand_ how your classes work, violations of Liskov are irrelevant.

Comment: Property of SHAPE ?? Have you meant SQUARE ? @MattCoubrough

Comment: No I mean the properties of ANY Shape. The whole concept is that you can swap out one shape for another, call a method with exactly the same signature and receive a valid result that doesn't break your code. For example, if I have a vector of shapes, of different types all inheriting from an abstract base class with a method called `Area()` I should be able to sum up the total area of all the shapes regardless of what shapes they are by calling Area() on each shape in turn and adding it to my total.

Comment: Is it possible to maintain Liskov Substitution Principle using overloading ? If possible, would you please give me an example ? I tried, but as I am very newbie, I was failed to find out such example. Actually, I'm confused, if Liskov Substitution Principle and OVERLOADING can be occurred concurrently at all. :( @MattCoubrough

Comment: In C++ contravariance of method arguments is seen as an entirely different method (overloading), so to meet the Liskov Substitution Principle you would need all subclasses to have the same method overloads.

Comment: Liskov-Schmiskov: passing `π` as a parameter is what I call an accident waiting to happen! (I'm sure it's just an example, but still...)

Comment: @paxdiablo The LSP is not right or wrong in general. It's (like every design principle) a guideline. Violating a principle is a code smell. Doing it one time doesn't hurt necessarily. But if the smell adds, you may get into trouble (and considering your rep you surely know by yourself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The LSP

[Liskov's Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (or LSP) is about abstraction. Imagine a class `Shape` and two classes `Square` and `Rectangle` deriving from `Shape`. Now `Shape` has a (virtual) method `getArea()`. You would expect it to return the area that is covered by the (concrete, instanced!) shape *regardless of what type it actually is*. So if you call `getArea()` on a `Shape` instance, *you don't care* whether it is a rectangle, a square *or any other shape you could think of*.

#### The Answer

Without overloading there wouldn't even be the need for something like the LSP, i.e. the answer is no, overloading and LSP doesn't contradict.

#### The Design

On the other hand, as paxdiablo pointed out, applying LSP depends on the design. In terms of the example above this means, maybe for some reason you actually *do* care wether you have a rectangle or not. Well, in that case the LSP says you should think about your design.

#### Your Code

I have to admit at this point, I don't really get where your code is aiming at. There is a class `Give_Area` which calculates the area of a cirle depending on the value of, uh, `pi`. A second method calculates a square that has `Radius` as its diagonal? Then there is the `Square` class. If `Validity()` returns false, what would that mean? A degenerated square maybe? My suggestions is: Reconsider your design. Ask yourself "what are the classes and objects I want to deal with?" and "what are the real-world objects I want do model?"

#### The Counterexample

How to violate the LSP is demonstrated at Wikipedia (link above). I will try to make up a second example. Say you have a class `Car` with a method `drive()`. Deriving classes (`RacingCar`, `Van`, ...) could specify speed, accelaration, etc. When a car drives into water (deep water, a lake, the sea) the car will break and the next garage is called. Now you derive a class `AmphibiousVehicle`. This one doesn't break on water and the garage would be called with no use. Did you expect that? Maybe yes. But if not, depending on further context I would think about a class `Vehicle` which is the base of `Car`. It would have a method `move()`. And `drive()` which belongs still to `Car` would call `move()` and might call (again ;-)) the garage in case of trouble. And so on.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. Actually I wanted to just overload a method. I wrote this code just as an example. There is no meaning of this code. As I am newbie in OOP, I was unable to find out if overloading and LSP contradict or not. Ok, now I know, overloading and LSP do not contradict. Now would you please give me an example, where LSP and overloading occurs concurrently ? Thanks in advance. Just want to familiar with such example.

Comment: Thanks for your edition. :) Now it's clear to me. :) Great answer. :)