# understanding virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
// multiple inheritance
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    Polygon (int a, int b) : width(a), height(b) {}
    virtual int area()=0;
    virtual void print(){
        cout << "area = " << area() << endl;
    };
};



class Rectangle: public Polygon{
  public:
    Rectangle (int a, int b) : Polygon(a,b) {}
    int area () { return width*height; }
    void print(){
        cout << "area = " << area() << endl;
    };
};

class Square: public Rectangle{
  public:
    Square (int a, int b) : Rectangle(a,b) {}
    int area () { return width*height/2; }
};

int main () {
  Square sq (4,5);
  sq.print ();
  return 0;
}
```

In this function, print calls area() of Square (not Rectangle). Why? Since area() in Rectangle is not virtual, it should call area() from Rectangle. Final result is 10. According to me it should be 20.

Comment: Since when is the area of a square width*height/2 ???

Answer (score 4):

> Since `area()` in `Rectangle` is not virtual, it should call `area()` from `Rectangle`

**It actually is `virtual`**, since it was declared `virtual` in the base class. This attribute is automatically transferred to inherited classes' member function  declarations.

See the standard, **Virtual functions [class.virtual]** (emphasis mine):

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, ***derived directly or indirectly***
>   from Base, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and refqualifier
>   (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (***whether or not it is
>   so declared***) and it *overrides* `Base::vf`.

---

**Side remark.** Derividg a square from a rectangle can be [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804908) as it violates Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: Shouldnt it call `area()` from `square`?

Comment: @StraightLine Well, yes. That's what I'm saying?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're saying "it should call `area()` from `Rectangle`"

Comment: @StraightLine No, this answer explains why it calls `area()` from `Square` rather then `Rectangle`.

Comment: @StraightLine All `area` functions are virtual, hence `Square`'s `area` should be called.

Comment: Ah. You were quoting the OP when you said "it should call `area()` from `Rectangle`". My misunderstanding